# PHP const not working?

Tags: php, class, constants

My class looks similar to this:

```
class Foo {
    const UNKNOWN = 2;

    public function doStuff($var) {
        if($var==UNKNOWN) {
            echo "Unknown state";
            return;
        }
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this error in `doStuff()`:

> Use of undefined constant UNKNOWN - assumed 'UNKNOWN'

What am I doing wrong? Can't I define custom constants?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use `self::` or the class name when accessing the constant in your class:

```
if($var == self::UNKNOWN) {
    echo "Unknown state";
    return;
}
```

Comment: FYI, The question-asker changed the code in their question after I posted my answer which is why my answer doesn't match the code int their question.

Comment: Yeah I updated it to be correct, sorry about that. Just waiting for the 13 minutes or whatever is needed before I can accept.

Comment: @JohnConde Much better ;)

Comment: @MightyPork get even uglier when the constant is an array

Answer (score 4):

Documentation has the example of defining the constants in the PHP class.

```
self:: will help 


  class Constants
{
  //define('MIN_VALUE', '0.0');  WRONG - Works OUTSIDE of a class definition.
  //define('MAX_VALUE', '1.0');  WRONG - Works OUTSIDE of a class definition.

  const MIN_VALUE = 0.0;      // RIGHT - Works INSIDE of a class definition.
  const MAX_VALUE = 1.0;      // RIGHT - Works INSIDE of a class definition.

  public static function getMinValue()
  {
    return self::MIN_VALUE;
  }

  public static function getMaxValue()
  {
    return self::MAX_VALUE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for using every dynamic field in php you must call `$this->field`
and for using every static field and const in php you must call `self::field`

example:

```
    class ApiController {

          public static $static= "";
          public $dynamic= "";

          public function __construct() {
          $a=$this->$dynamic;
          $b=self::$static;
    }
  }
```